# Creating a file inside DocumentsLibrary

Tags: c#, serialization, xamarin, uwp, storage

I've created an app where I save the user data into an xml file and I want that xml file to be in the documents library.
The app is created in PCL but my main target is an UWP device (phone).I used DependencyService for this because there is no System.IO.FileStream in the PCL.

So here I create the file on click in my PCL:

```
private void Senden_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var s = DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>().MakeFileStream();
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s, Encoding.UTF8);
            XMLDaten xmldat = new XMLDaten(); //Seriazable Class
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLDaten));
            serializer.Serialize(sw, xmldat);
            s.Dispose();
        }
```

this is the class I created in the UWP project:

```
namespace myProject.UWP
{
    public class FileHelper: IFileHelper
    {
        public FileHelper() { }

        public Stream MakeFileStream()
        {
            StorageFolder sf = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
            var path = sf.Path;
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@path + "\\daten.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            return fileStream;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the interface I created (it's in a folder called classes):

```
namespace myProject.classes
{

    public interface  IFileHelper
    {
        Stream MakeFileStreamAsync();

    }
}
```

Unfortunately DocumentsLibrary returns an empty path. How can I get around this? I've seen a few examples but nothing that would let the application be as simple as it is without having to use tasks and async classes. Before you ask, yes I have added the DocumentsLibrary capability in the Package.appxManifest and added the needed extensions so it is possible to write files into the documents library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are already Capabilities then just add the line:

```
<uap:Capability Name="documentsLibrary" />
```

And, that’s not all. Next you need to tell it which documents it can access:

```
  <Extensions>
    <uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
      <uap:FileTypeAssociation Name=".txt">
        <uap:DisplayName>Text</uap:DisplayName>
        <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
          <uap:FileType>.jpg</uap:FileType>
          <uap:FileType>.txt</uap:FileType>
          <uap:FileType>.gif</uap:FileType>
          <uap:FileType>.doc</uap:FileType>
          <uap:FileType>.xls</uap:FileType>
          <uap:FileType>.xml</uap:FileType>
        </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
      </uap:FileTypeAssociation>
    </uap:Extension>
  </Extensions>
```

> Unfortunately DocumentsLibrary returns an empty path.

Because DocumentsLibrary is a virtual location representing a collection of different locations and files, it will not have a path.

> In the Remarks of [`KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.KnownFolders#Windows_Storage_KnownFolders_DocumentsLibrary) property, we can find that
>   Libraries let users view related content in a single location. A library is a virtual folder. The folders in a library remain in their original locations. Learn more about libraries in Windows Libraries.

`StorageFolder.Path` property can get the full path of the current folder in the file system, but only if the path is available. As Music Library is a virtual folder, the file system path is not available. So it always returns empty string.

As you already have StorageFolder, use it to create a StorageFile and then get stream from it with one of its methods, for example:

```
 public IRandomAccessStream MakeFileStream()
  {
      var task = MakeFileStreamAsync();
      task.Wait();
      return task.Result;
  }

  public async Task<IRandomAccessStream> MakeFileStreamAsync()
  {
      StorageFolder sf = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;

      var file = await sf.CreateFileAsync("daten.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

      using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
      {
          return stream;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @NicoZhu ! As written in my first code segment, I need a FileStream for the StreamWriter sw in my button_clicked handler as that's the only valid overload here. I will try your solution and report whether or not Stream is also a valid type for the StreamWriter overload.

Comment: I edited my question so you could see the interface too. I don't quite get what public IRandomAccessStream MakeFileStream(){...} does or how I'm supposed to change my IFileHelper interface to get the work done, any advice?

Comment: `public IRandomAccessStream MakeFileStream()` is `IFileHelper` interface method. And it will execute `the public async Task<IRandomAccessStream> MakeFileStreamAsync()` method.

Comment: I get the "Interface members cannot have a definition" error in the `public IRandomAccessStream MakeFileStream()` interface method.

Comment: Ok got it, I had to return task.Result.AsStream();